# How to fill a jframe table from an arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, jframe

I have a jtable that I created using java GUI and I need to fill from an arraylist. I'm not familiar with java and I have no idea how to fill a jTable. I don't know if I need to use TableModel or just JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames). This is my code:

```
 public void filltable(){

    ArrayList A=new ArrayList();
    jframe4 j=new jframe4();
    String m=j.getloggedemail();

  //  A=s.getEmails(m);
  //this is an example of my arraylist

    A.add("sender@gmail.com");
    A.add("my subject");
    A.add("hiiii");

    try {
        String[] columnNames = {"Sender",
                        "Subject",
                        "Body",
                     };

         //here I need to fill my table


            }

        catch(Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

This is the declaration of jTable1 that I need to fill:

```
   jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Sender", "Subject", "Body"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

Comment: With list, it's complicated to fill the Table. How you can define a row. A row will have a set of fields. In list how you will break into rows.?

Comment: `A.add("sender@gmail.com");
    A.add("my subject");
    A.add("hiiii");`  These should not be successive rows/elements of an `ArrayList` but instead attributes of a single `Email` object.  Then you might create a table model from a collection of the `Email` objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this task is well described in the Java Tutorial via [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if I need to use TableModel or just JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)

Depends on your needs, you can do either. I will demonstrate how to use the latter. If you want to use your own `TableModel`, see the link in @Andrew Thompson's comment.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    Example() {

        String[] colNames = new String[] {"Sender", "Subject", "Body"};

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("sender@gmail.com");
        list.add("my subject");
        list.add("hiiii");
        list.add("sender2@gmail.com");
        list.add("my subject2");
        list.add("hiiii2");

        String[][] rowData = new String[list.size() / colNames.length][colNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowData[i].length; j++) {
                rowData[i][j] = list.get(i * colNames.length + j);
            }
        }

        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, colNames);

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Example();
    }
}
```

Just note that if the list does not contain 3 elements in a row, the whole row will not be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom bean class and specify your data then load it to your table. Even I have done similar work. I've modified for your data.

```
public class ListToJtable {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Message> messags = new ArrayList<>();
    Message message = new Message("sender@gmail.com", "my subject", "hiiii");
    messags.add(message);
    Message message1 = new Message("sender1@gmail.com", "my subject1",
            "hiiii1");
    messags.add(message1);
    JTable t = new JTable();
    t.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {}, 
            new String[] { "Sender", "Subject", "Body" }));
    addToTable(messags, t);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(t);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void addToTable(List<Message> messags, JTable jTable) {
    for (Message message : messags) {
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {
                message.getSender(), message.getSubject(),
                message.getBody() });
    }
}

}


public class Message {

String sender;
String subject;
String body;
public Message(String a1,String a2,String a3){
    sender = a1;
    subject = a2;
    body = a3;
}
public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}
public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

}
```