# Import XLS file with multiple columns to JTable

Tags: java, excel, import, jtable

I am loosing second day in searching the way to import XLS file to JTable. The task is clear and easy - one netbeans application with import button and all the excel information to be parsed in JTable (exactly copy of XLS file). I found a video of what I exactly want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed9nQD1NxrQ - but there is no code, only demo. I also find a lot of stuff about Apache POI and jxl library but all stuffs in internet did not work for me. I am posting the code of the function which should parse the file:

```
public void process() throws IOException, BiffException{
    File file=new File("D:\\0244D600.xls");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
    jxl.Workbook wb=jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
    jxl.Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);
    int row=s.getRows(); 
    int col=s.getColumns();
    headers.clear();
     for (int i = 0; i <row; i++) { 
      for (int j = 0; j <col; j++) { 
         jxl.Cell c=s.getCell(j, i); 
          System.out.print(c.getContents()+"\t\t");    
          arr.add(c.toString());
      } 
      System.out.println(""); 
  } 

}
```

It is working and it is giving me nice output in console:

```
i10     02/05/2019      84,218      
i10     03/05/2019      74,8        
i10     07/05/2019      69,786      
i10     08/05/2019      38,623      
i10     09/05/2019      90,021      
i10     10/05/2019      52,493      
i10     13/05/2019      87,757
```

But I want this to be stored in my JTable. I only could do this with first column if I use ArrayList. Can someone help me or explain the code behind the video? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using netbeans. It is easy to add/create table. The problem is the idea behind this - how to import excel information in JTable. Please read question again!

Comment: does something like this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185246/how-to-fill-a-jframe-table-from-an-arraylist

Comment: not at all, I have big excel file which has to be parsed in JTable.

Comment: Literally the video I shared is all I want.

Comment: You have posted code and are able to read the XLS file. To put it into a JTable, like shown in the vid, you do need to add some DataModel and the JTable, which is shown in the above mentioned link. Still don't know what you are up to. The vid shows, that a table is filled, which is exactly what the link provides.